# Extends Jquery ajax complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm using jQuery ajax to do some requests to the server. I have to add some validations after the content is loaded (error handling). The easiest way is by adding the validation on the `success()` callback. However, I would need to implement that callback in all the implementations I already have. Is there a way to extend the success callback? Something that will be called before the rest of the callback code? This way I can add the validations for each success in ONE place, and be executed every time a success callback is called.

I tried `preFilters`, converters, but they don't fit my needs.

Comment: The fact that you'll have to copy paste the validations everywhere, sounds a little... not right. Maybe you should look into abstracting the process a little more and extract the common things.

Comment: I think I'll do that, but I'll still have to refactor every ajax call. (by the way, I have 182 calls in the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept **an array of functions**. Each function will be called in turn.

So, something like this should work

```
$.ajax(url, {
    success: [
        commonfunction,
        function(...){ /* code */ }
    ],
});
```

Though you will still have to modify *some* code.

Comment: thanks. This solves part of my problem, I use different libraries like data tables and such that uses AJAX. I'll find a way for the libraries. For the moment I will apply the array and create a new level for ajax, this means instead of calling $.AJAX, create $.myAjax that simply use my methods and then the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for AJAX request with [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and [$.ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

Comment: If I set a default success, and then an implementation sets a new success, will both be executed?

Comment: @user1766688 Yes. At least in case of `.ajaxSuccess`. But it also seems that functions registered with `.ajaxSuccess` are executed *after* the success functions of an AJAX request.